# How to pass a \def parameter to an inner command (StrSubstitute)?

Tags: macros, programming, strings

I'm attempting to create 2 macros to simulate an array list as in Java for example. I'm using **xstring StrSubstitute** for this purpose, but I'm having a problem.
Below is the code, it's a bit long as it contains the macros plus the test document.

The currently active StrSubstitute line is working as it is specifying the recipient of the substitution explicitly (`\Cities`).

The 1st commented StrSubstitute line (using `\csname #1\endcsname`) on the other hand causes the following TeX error :

```
! Extra \endcsname.
<argument> \csname testAL\endcsname 

l.21 \addElementToArrayList{testAL}{Paris}
```

The 2nd commented line (using just `#1`) causes the following error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
            \inaccessible 
l.21 \addElementToArrayList{testAL}{Paris}
```

I tried to read some TeX resources, but I am not able to make it work and I find lots of possibilities (`\def`, `\edef`, `\noexpand`...)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{xstring}    %will use this package for the internal list structure

\def\ARRAYENDSENTINEL{@@}   %indicates array end
\def\ARRAYSEPARATOR{,}      %element separator

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Macro to create a new list:
%Parameters: <list name>
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\newArrayList#1{%
      \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Macro to append element on a list:
%Parameters: <list name>, <element to add>
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\addElementToArrayList#1#2{
  \StrSubstitute[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}{\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}{\ARRAYSEPARATOR #2\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}[\Cities] %working
  %\StrSubstitute[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}{\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}{\ARRAYSEPARATOR #2\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}[\csname #1\endcsname] %NOT working!
  %\StrSubstitute[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}{\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}{\ARRAYSEPARATOR #2\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}[#1] %NOT working either!
}

%opening
\title{Testing ArrayList}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newArrayList{Cities}

Contents of Cities: \textbf{[\Cities]}

\addElementToArrayList{Cities}{Paris}

Contents of Cities: \textbf{[\Cities]}

\addElementToArrayList{Cities}{London}

Contents of Cities: \textbf{[\Cities]}

\addElementToArrayList{Cities}{Rome}

Contents of Cities: \textbf{[\Cities]}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always state the error you get. This can help a lot with tracking down the cause. Just saying "does not work" isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `\csname foo\endcsname` at locations were `\foo` is required, e.g. `\def\csname foo\endcsname{...}` will redefine `\csname` with `foo\endcsname` as a parameter text and `...` as replacement text. You need to expand `\csname foo\endcsname` first once to build `\foo`. The `\expandafter` primitive helps you here. It expands the token (=~ macro or character) after the following token once. So `\expandafter\def\csname foo\endcsname{...}` will expand to `\def\foo{...}` so that `\foo` is defined. A problem here is that you might need many `\expandafter` if you want to expand the `\csname ...\endcsname` at the end of a long line.

In this case it is better to either store the line in a temporary macro:

```
\def\addElementToArrayList#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\temp{\endgroup\StrSubstitute[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}{\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}{\ARRAYSEPARATOR #2\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}[}%
  \expandafter\temp\csname #1\endcsname]%
}
```

or by expanding the `\csname ...\endcsname` first and feeding it to a second macro:

```
\def\addElementToArrayList#1{%
  \expandafter\addElementToArrayListX\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}%
}

\def\addElementToArrayListX#1#2{%
  \StrSubstitute[1]{#1}{\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}{\ARRAYSEPARATOR #2\ARRAYENDSENTINEL}[#1]%
}
```

Here we use two `\expandafter`s in a row to "jump over" `\addElementToArrayListX` and `{`. Note that it is perfectly OK to read the second argument only with the second macro.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions working though seem tricky (too advanced fr me). I updated the question by adding another statement using just #1 without \csname. I wonder why it doesn't work unlike your second solution which seems a little similar.

Comment: @John Kirollos: No, that doesn't work. You might just pass `\Cities` instead of `Cities` to your macro, then you can use `#1` directly (in both places).